# Design: Spring Integration: Jdbc-Inbound-adapter in Clustered Environment

Tags: spring-integration

We have clustered environment with 2 nodes in Oracle Weblogic 10.3.6 server and it is Round-Robin.

I have service which goes and gets the message from a external system and puts them in the Database (Oracle DB).

I am using a jdbc-inbound-adapter to convert these messages and pass it to the channels.
And to have a message processed only once. I am planning to have a column(NODE_NAME) in the DB-table. When the first service which gets the message from the external system also updates the column with the NODE_NAME (weblogic.Name). In the SELECT query of jdbc-inbound-adapter if I specify the NODE_NAME then the messages would be processed only once.

i.e. If the Service1(of Node1) saves the message in DB then inbound-adapter1 (of node1) passes the message to channel.

```
Example: 
<si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInboundAdapter"
    channel="queueChannel" data-source="myDataSource"
    auto-startup="true"
    query="SELECT * FROM STAGE_TABLE WHERE STATUS='WAITING' and NODE_NAME = '${weblogic.Name}'"
    update="UPDATE STAGE_TABLE SET STATUS='IN_PROGRESS' WHERE ID IN (:Id)"
    max-rows-per-poll="100" row-mapper="rowMapper"
    update-per-row="true">

    <si:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <si:advice-chain> 
            <ref bean="txAdvice"/> 
            <ref bean="inboundAdapterConfiguration"/> 
        </si:advice-chain>
    </si:poller>
</si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Is this a good design?

By second approach: using the below Select SQL in the jdbc-inbound-adapter but I am guessing this would fail as I am using Oracle Database.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE STATUS='WAITING' FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

It would be great if some one could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` is exactly Oracle's feature - http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2060739900346201280.

Comment: Then I can go ahead and use this Select SQL. I came across this post but I am not sure if the user faced any challenges as it was not clear from his response: [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/113249-jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter-concurrent-problem-in-cluster)

Comment: If you are in doubt as, here is a code from Spring Integration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/store/channel/OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider.java#L39, where we use the same statement

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` is exactly Oracle's feature - [https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2060739900346201280](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2060739900346201280)

If you are in doubt as, here is a code from Spring Integration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/store/channel/OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider.java#L39